# Creating a Vector from a dataframe that discriminates values based on another column in r

Tags: r

Working in r here. I have a data frame with two columns, one that qualitatively describes body site of a sample (v1) (gut, skin), and another which is quantitative (v2). I would like to create a vector of all the values for when body site equals "gut" (Omitting all other values) Does anyone know how to do this?

````
v2 <- c(120, 125,0,0)
data.frame(v1,v2)

    v1  v2
1  gut 120
2 gut, 125
3 skin   0
4 skin   0 ```
````

Comment: You can use `subset(df1, v1 == 'gut', select = v2)[,1]` or `with(df1, v2[v1 == 'gut'])`

Comment: To add to @Akrun ‘s answer you could also use `df[df$V1 == “gut”,]`

Answer (score 0):

In dplyr, you can do

```
library(dplyr)
v1 <- c('gut','gut','skin','skin')
v2 <- c(120, 125,0,0)
result <- data.frame(v1,v2) %>% 
filter(v1 == 'gut') %>%
select(v2)
```